# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, fetch

The full error is: *TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window' : The provided value is not of type '(sequence<sequence> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)'*. I am trying to fetch from the [Jenkins api](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/) using reactjs and I can't resolve this issue, I have no idea what is causing this. I am only trying to log into the console to test the api response. Here is my code

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://PrivateServerURLJenkins/api/json?pretty=true', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: 'Authorization: Basic APIToken',
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                List test
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`headers` needs to be either a sequence of sequences (array of arrays) or a record (an object with string values).

You are passing it a plain string.

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic APIToken',
}
```